# Prepare accounts using some grouping

Tags: vba, excel

I have to prepare accounts using some grouping. For this purpose I have to arrange data in a refine form apply "PivotTable" and VLOOKUP.

The problem is the Excel sheet contains more than 44,000 rows.

I am attaching two picture the first one is of existing data format and second one in which figures are highlighted.

I want to do this highlighted work using macro.

[First one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6u6N.png)
[image]

[what i want to do(second one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as9tD.png)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean you "want to do this highlighted work using [a] macro"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @adjit Please click above stated links: (First one )what i want to do(second one)
These are pictures.

Comment: The ultimate "How to ask a VBA question on SO":
1. Write down all the steps that you want your code to accomplish
2. Write out the pseudocode to accomplish your goal
3. Break out each of those steps and Google or search SO for the code related to that step
4. Replace the pseduocode with real code and test. Debug errors.
5. If there are errors you can't get around through searching or trial and error, THEN you can ask a new question on SO.

Answer (score -2):

You have to approach your problem logically - what needs to happen in order to fill in the Account number in column C?

Since your data looks pretty uniform you can make use of magic numbers, the code doesn't need to be perfect, just needs to get the job done.

```
iRow = row index - set this to your first account number row (ie 47 / 51 / 56 - per your pictures)
{
    accountNumber = [value at](Column B, iRow)

    While ((Column C, iRow) <> empty) {
        set (Column C, iRow) = accountNumber
        iRow ++ (increment your row index) 
    }

    iRow += 2 (skip 2 rows after your while loop to get to the next row with the account number)
} Repeat
```